# Attempting to replace an image in a table on a click

Tags: javascript, html, image, png

I am attempting to replace an image in a table on a click. I am not using JQuery; I am only Javascript to achieve this task. I think I have narrowed down the problem to the comment in the JavaScript code below. All other searches have ended me up with how to change image sources when they are part of the body etc. not part of a cell. I ran through other possible ways as well but for some reason I can't get it to work. Thanks so much!

HTML (Just cut out so you could see what each of the variables is referring to)

```
<td class="block"><img class="PieceImg" src="Directory/BlankSpace.png"></td>
```

JavaScript

```
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("PieceImg");

for(var j = 0; j<cells.length;j++)
{
    var cell = cells[j];
    cell.addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        cell.src="Directory/RedPiece.png"; // This is the problem
        alert('Test');
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Error in the console?

Comment: The problem is that when I click on the cell the image does not switch; no error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are running your JavaScript once the DOM is loaded, you should just have to replace `cell.src` with `this.src`.

```
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("PieceImg");

for(var j = 0; j<cells.length;j++)
{
  var cell = cells[j];
  cell.addEventListener("click", function()
  {
    // Replace cell. with this.
    this.src="Directory/RedPiece.png";
    alert('Test');
  })
}
```

The reason is simple: every time you loop, you create a variable called "cell" (`var cell = cells[j];`).  This non-global variable is overwritten every time the loop is run.  If you are running this code inside of a function, your `cell` variable will not even exist when it comes time to change the src.  It will be `undefined`.  Note that making this variable global would result in `cell` being the last element by class name `PieceImg`, so that wouldn't work any better.

However, if you use `this` instead, you will be referencing the "clicked" (remember `addEventListener("click")`) element when you click it, in this case your image.  Thus you are able to change the src.  Do a console.log of "this" inside your eventListener to see more things you can access.  This gives a similar effect as adding the "click" handler inline:

```
<img src="fox.png" onclick="alert(this.src);" alt="Fox" />
```

Let me know if that makes sense to you.

Here's a fully function fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7se0vyf5/

Comment: Thanks so much it works! Can I get a more in-depth explanation as to why this.src is required instead of cell.src?

Comment: Sure thing.  I just added it to my answer.

Comment: Makes Perfect Sense. Thanks again!

Comment: Great.  Don't forget to mark it as answered for anyone who might find it with Google later.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the for loop and the reference of the variable. It does not keep the state when you assign the event handler.

```js
var cells = document.getElementsByClassName("PieceImg");

for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
  var cell = cells[j];
  (function(cell){
      cell.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(cell);
        cell.src = "Directory/RedPiece.png"; // This is the problem
        alert('Test');
      });
    }(cell));
      
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="block">
      <img class="PieceImg" src="Directory/BlankSpace.png">
    </td>
    <td class="block">
      <img class="PieceImg" src="Directory/BlankSpace.png">
    </td>
    <td class="block">
      <img class="PieceImg" src="Directory/BlankSpace.png">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```